# How can I parse the text inside a cell and return a certain string or value using code in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

As an example, let's say I have a cell containing the following text:

```
 +8% melee attack skill for infantry units (army only)
```

The functions that I want to create should return these strings:

- returnBuffType(): melee attack
- returnValue(): +8%
- returnTarget(): infantry units
- returnScope(): army

That's what I want to do to save myself from doing it by hand, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0):

With only one example, I've made an assumption that your format will always be:

`***% *** *** skill for *** *** (***`

If so,

`=REGEXEXTRACT($A1,"\ (.*)\ skill")` for `melee attack`

`=REGEXEXTRACT($A1,"^(.*%)\ ")` for `+8%`

`=REGEXEXTRACT($A1,"for\ (.*)\ \(.*")` for `infantry units`

`=REGEXEXTRACT($A1,"\((.*)\ ")` for `army`

Comment: nvm I just learned how to use javascript and I've been creating functions to search for key words